# The meaning of "I am rotting on the inside"?

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the meaning of a sentence.
Please consider the following sentence:

> I look fine from the outside, but I am ***rotting on the inside***.

Does this sentence mean that I look okay from others' perspectives but I'm actually not okay at all?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means.

Comment: Consider an analogy, "The finest looking apple can be rotten to the core". Things might look good from the outside but the situation is different inside.

Comment: @gotube, That comment contains an answer to the question, and should not have been converted.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is reminiscent of a lyric by Chris Cornell which goes: "I'm looking California and feeling Minnesota"

Yes, the meaning is quite clear.

A more typical way of saying this might be "but I feel like..." as in "I feel like I am rotting on the inside" or "I feel like **** on the inside". By excluding the word "feel", it becomes a metaphorical/figurative usage that makes the sense stronger.